# Show/Hide virtual keyboard on Maui Blazor

Tags: c#, android, maui-blazor

i need a way to programatically show/hide the virtual keyboard on a Maui Blazor App for the Android platform.

I am creating an app for a barcodescanner device (Android device with integrated Barcodescanner).

It' realy annoying to get the keyboard being popped up everytime you enter a inputfield.

Is there any way to do this? It's crazy how less information you get for this through the internet :(

I already tried to change the inputtype to "none" but that lets me also not scan either.
I can disable the popup globally for the whole device but thats not realy a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put the following code into the MainActivity.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.Window.SetFlags(Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.NotFocusable, Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.NotFocusable);
    //this will disable the soft keyboard in the whole app.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the inputmode tag. Set it to "" for default behaviour. So depending on inputtype it will display a numeric or alpha numeric keyboard.When set to none, it will not display the keyboard.

I have it working using Blazor WASM. Using Blazor Server I'm still struggeling with the on click and on focus events. Even when the keyboard should be hidden initially, it should still be possible to display it by clicking on the input. When ServerPrerender is enabled this method is not working at all, when when you disable it, it works 90% for me.

So if you do not want the keyboard at all for some inputs, then just use inputmode="none".

Regards, Nico